# Trying to import and run a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm desperatly trying to run a friend's laravel program on my PC.

I can run the default Laravel webpage.

I copy and paste the project directory and run `composer update` or `composer install` in cmd prompt. Everything here seems to work fine

[image]

Then when i try to run this URL `http://127.0.0.1/myproject/public/`, this error shows:

[image]

I already tried to reinstall composer but it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas ?

Edit:

if i run `php artisan dump-autoload`:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting the vendor map and running composer install again?

Comment: Maybe you need to check your PHP version > 5.5.9

Comment: I tried yes, it doesn't change anything. It loads file from cache anyway. I have PHP 5.6.16 version

Comment: Try running the  "php artisan dump-autoload" command in cmd or terminal

Comment: I edited my question Jhonny

Comment: try run `composer update --no-scripts`

Comment: doesn't work either, it does the same as composer update

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you set 777 permission to "storage" and "bootstrap/cache" folders:

Comment: How can i do such thing on windows ?

Comment: What is your PHP version ?, the most issue is in your version because PHP less than 5.5 (I think), can't understand the code in app.php: App\Http\Kernel::class

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem in composer.json file. Try to manually check composer. json file and find out which dependency is causing the problem. Also you can try deleting composer.lock file and vendor directory and then running `composer install`.